# Wordpress: Trigger a function when any post is published

Tags: php, function, eventtrigger

I have written a function and want to make it trigger when any post is published on my website.

I have tried everything, but still doesn't work. So, I post the following code, just in case somebody helps with it. :)

```
function run_when_post_published(){
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "wp");
        .blablabla

            $mysqli->close();

    }
    add_action('publish_post', 'run_when_post_published');
```

Can you tell what's wrong? Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned in WordPress doc :

publish_post is an action triggered whenever a post is updated and its new status is "publish".

[publish_post Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post)

as i understand from your question you need to trigger an function whenever post has been added regardless of post status so here is the correct hook to use

```
function run_when_post_published( $post_id, $post, $update){
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "wp");
  .blablabla
     $mysqli->close();

}
add_action('save_post', 'run_when_post_published', 10, 3);
```

[save_post Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)